# I need help getting the JQuery Function slideDown to work in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the script in my html code. The video div is not displayed because it cant be displayed in the beginning. Any ideas why this is not sliding down and showing?
Here is the html code and java script code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Team Songs</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
$(document.body).ready(function () 
{ 
      if ($("#video").is(":hidden")) {
      $("#video").slideDown("slow");
      } 
     else {
         $("#video").hide();
         }
 });

 </script> 
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id ="content">
 <div id="header"> 
 <h1>Software Picture</h1>
 </div>
 <span id="menu">
 <ul>
 <li>Main Tab</li>
 <li>Video Tab</li>
 <li>Third Tab</li>
 <li>Fourth Tab</li>
 </ul>
 </span>
 <div id="video"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="footer">

 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
 @charset "utf-8";
 /* CSS Document */

 body
 {
     background-color:#333;
 }
 #content
 {
     width:800px;   
     border:solid 1px #FFFFFF;
     margin:auto;
 }
 #header
 {
     float:left;
     margin:0px;
     width:800px;
     height:100px;  
     text-align:center;
     background-color:#FFF;
 }
 #menu
 {
 float:left;
width:800px;
height:50px;
width:800px;
 }
 #menu ul
 {
padding:0px;
list-style-type:none;
 } 
 #menu li
 {  
    float:left;
  padding:5px 30px;
   font-size:20px;
   color:#FFFFFF;
   border-right:solid 2px #FFF;
 }
 #video
{
   display:none;
   float:left;
   width:800px;
   height:500px;
   background-color:#000000;    
} 
#footer
{
   width:800px; 
   margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
```

with

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
</script>
<script>
```

and I think you should be fine

Comment: It worked after that. How come that was the case? don't I need to use the jquery source to use its functions

Comment: You cannot include an external js and inline js code like that. You need different script tags to do this. They don't have to be in the same script tag for the one to see the other, meaning to use jquery functions in the another script tag. By the way, I think you accepted the wrong answer, since my answer did the trick ;)

Comment: I didn't realize you cant give people partial credit. Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your code is to show the div if it is already hidden and show if it is not visible.

Your else condition is always being executed so the video div will be always hidden.

Change the  `$("#video").hide();` to  `$("#video").fadeOut("slow");` then you can see it is going away when the dom finished loading.

IF you want to show the vide div, hide the div initially. So that it will be displayed

```
<div id="video" style="display:none;">
     <h3>Video div content </h3>
    </div>
 </div>
```

jsfiddle sample for that : http://jsfiddle.net/uzARd/4/

Comment: I tried what you had said and it still seemed to not work. I even placed two alert statements before the if statement and inside of it. Can you see maybe any syntactical errors with this?

Comment: check in the firebug console what is the error. i guess some other script error. did you check my jsfiddle ?

Comment: Yeah it worked on jsfiddle but not on the browser I had to make seperate script tags

Comment: @tdelaney18 : Then i guess some other script error in your page. You may need to do some clean up

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just use `$("#video").slideToggle();` instead of the if else check?
and also set the display:none property initially

Answer (score 0):

use seperate script tag for both like

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () 
{ 
      if ($("#video").is(":hidden")) {
      $("#video").slideDown('slow');
      } 
     else {
         $("#video").hide();
         }
 });

</script>
```